# event error :unhandled event er

Tags: java, node.js

```
var uploadLogoAdImage = function (req, res) {
    var appName = req.params.appName;
    var ftpEndPointPath = '${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome}/content/';
    var s3_bucket = 'w-a-images';
    var uploadParams = {
        Bucket: s3_bucket,
        Key: '',
        Body: '',
        ACL: 'public-read'
    };
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, './uploadTemp/');
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            var datetimestamp = Date.now();
            cb(null, file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length - 2] + '-' + datetimestamp + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length - 1]);
        }
    });
    var upload = multer({
        storage: storage
    }).single('file');
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        console.log(req.file);
        if (err) {
            res.json({ error_code: 1, err_desc: err });
            return;
        }
        var filePathStr = req.file.path;
        var splitter = filePathStr.toString().split('\\');
        var fileName = splitter[1];
        var file = filePathStr;
        var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
        var read_file = fs.readFileSync(file);
        fileStream.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('File Error', err);
        });
        var client = new Client();
        var ftpConfig = {
            host: '13.126.230.30',
            port: 21,
            user: 'wftp',
            password: 'xxxxxxxxx'
        }
        client.connect(ftpConfig);
        uploadParams.Body = fileStream;
        uploadParams.Key = 'l_ads/' + path.basename(file);
        s3.upload(uploadParams, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error", err);
            }
            if (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
        client.on('ready', function () {
            client.put(filePathStr, './' + fileName, function (ftpErr) {
                if (ftpErr) {
                    console.log(ftpErr);
                } else {
                    client.end();
                    res.status(200).json({
                        message: 'success',
                        videoUrl: 'https://wowstream-ads-images.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/' + uploadParams.Key,
                        ftpPath: ftpEndPointPath + fileName,
                        fileSize: req.file.size,
                        fileName: fileName
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

ERROR:

events.js:183
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 13.126.230.30:21
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I tried all the things but still the same error.I insatll new version of fs package and iconic script both are does not work.In S3 files were upload afterthat i didn't get proper response.

i tried all those things whatever they said.I did not understand where the error throws.The data are stored in the s3 then it throw event unhandled error.Sometimes connection refused sometimes timeout error coming.

Since two days i tried all methods and i did not get any solution

Comment: What does [tag:java] has to do with your question?

Comment: You will need to create a [MCVE] first. Most of your code has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: s3.upload(uploadParams, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error", err);
            }
            if (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        }); //here is the problem  while upload the file

Comment: Please do read what a [MCVE] is. Nobody's going to fish fragments of code from comments to debug it for you.